# When I fork a repository can I disconnected the fork from the original project

Tags: git

I have a base repository for all my projects, I want to fork from that for all new projects but NOT stay current with the original fork.

I can do this by just cloning the original project and changing the origin of the project to a new repository.

But I am wondering if a more elegant solution exists.

My current workflow is on bitbucket.

One of the issues with the clone process is it does not force new projects to be current, the user can just copy the old clone and change origin.

Really all I want to do is fork and then disconnected the new repository with the one it was forked from.

This would remove the default pull request behavior, that is pull requests default to the old repository.

This would also cause the new repository to not be able to be synced with the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Really all I want to do is fork and then disconnected the new repository with the one it was forked from.*

Instead of forking via the web interface, do it manually.

1. Clone the existing project: `git clone`.
2. Create a new project on Bitbucket (or wherever).
3. Change `origin` on your clone to the new Bitbucket project: `git remote set-url origin <new-url>`.
4. `git push`

As far as the Bitbucket web interface is concerned, this is a new project with no attachment to the old one.  In reality they probably share the same disk space on Bitbucket since they share the same objects, but this is just an internal space saving measure.

I think this is what you're already doing and, while it would be nice if Bitbucket offered a "detach" button for forked projects, it's plenty "elegant".

You can always sync with the old one if you want to by adding a remote to the old project. `git remote add old-project <old-project-url>`

Comment: Right that is what we do when we need to do this.  But many of my team members don't have git experience so I am trying to keep it as simple as possible.  But the reality seems to be, don't fork if you want the project to be independent of the origin.

Comment: @user3304698 This shouldn't something people normally need to do. Now I have to ask: why are people doing this often enough that it needs to be simple? Should they be using branches instead?

Comment: The developers are starting a new project for Client X the end result will be client X's application.  The repository that is forked is just the current base for all clients.  This is done dozens of times per week and with out the base repository the developers were cut and pasting a bunch of files to get there start up and running, even though everyone was suppose to be using the same starting base.  The developers are mostly front end and like the idea of just clicking fork cloning that and never touching terminal.  Basically I am just going to have them Clone and change the origin